# Possible to exclude dependency from Meteor.autorun?

Tags: meteor

We're using Meteor.autorun to look for changes in a 'filters' Session variable, make two asynchronous calls to the server for the filtered data and update two 'list' Session variables with the results. In another .autorun function, the script waits for changes in the list Session variables, and then turns on applicable templates.

So,

```
Meteor.autorun(function(){

    set_search_session(Session.get('filters'));

    render_templates(
         Session.get('places'),
         Session.get('awards')
    );

});

var set_search_session = function(filters) {
      Meteor.call('search_places', filters.places, function(error, data) {
          Session.set('places', data);
      };
      Meteor.call('search_awards', filters.awards, function(error, data) {
          Session.set('awards', data);
      };
};

var render_templates = function(places, awards) {
      var filters = Session.get('filters');
      if (!awards && _.isUndefined(filters['neighborhood'])) {
           Session.set('template', 'place_detail');
      };
};
```

The problem is that the render_templates function is run twice, as it is apparently still dependent on Session.get('filters'). So in any autorun function, it looks like you're unable use a Session.get() function that is separate from the one you're observing changes on.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate reasons that changing `filters` calls `render_templates`. One is that `render_templates` is called within the same autorun as a `Session.get('filters')`; the other is that `render_templates` itself calls `Session.get('filters')`.

To fix the former, split the autorun into two separate autoruns:

```
Meteor.autorun(function(){
    set_search_session(Session.get('filters'));
});
Meteor.autorun(function(){
    render_templates(
         Session.get('places'),
         Session.get('awards')
    );    
});
```

To fix the latter, perhaps move the "neighborhoods" field out of `Session.get('filters')` into its own Session field?

Comment: I avoided creating multiple filter session variables so that the entire filter can be reset or updated with one Session.set. I ended up including the filter as a separate property in the 'awards' and 'places' session variable. Creating separate Meteor.autorun functions worked well. Not sure if other people have similar challenges, but it might be useful to be able to isolate dependencies. You folks are doing great things with meteor and the internet is already a better place to work.

Comment: Yes, right now the easiest way to isolate dependencies is to put them in separate Session variables :) You can also make your own reactive data structures using `Context` or `ContextSet` directly; Session is just the easiest way provided to accomplish most straightforward reactive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the game here but I ran into the same problem (I needed to modify the current user when a reactive var changed, but not when the user changed, I was using Meteor.user() inside the autorun).

The answer came from the Tracker Manual: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Tracker-Manual#ignoring-changes-to-certain-reactive-values

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
    Tracker.nonreactive(function () {
        console.log("DEBUG: current game umpire is " + game.get("umpire"));
    });
    console.log("The game score is now " + game.get("score") + "!");
});
```